# How to keep packed structs member sorted by declaration order in Doxygen

Tags: c++, struct, doxygen, packed

I use doxygen to document a C++ codebase which uses some packed structs to represent communication buffers. I usually like the alphabetical order of members doxygen uses because it makes it easier to find something in the documentation. However, I'd prefer the documentation of my packed structs to show the fields in the order I've declared them, because in that case, the order of declaration matters (among other things, the documentation of some fields like the ones representing CRC values refers to some other fields in the same struct).

Is there a way to choose the order of the fields individually for a specific struct or is [SORT_MEMBER_DOCS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_sort_member_docs) the only (global) way to control sorting?

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible. As a workaround you could generate the doc for that single file seperately with its own config file

Comment: @tobi303 Thank you for your comment. That was my understanding from what I've seen online and in the Doxygen's manual too. Too bad :-/ I'll see if I can patch Doxygen to make do what I want.

Comment: the only chance is see is to override the global setting on a per file basis, but I guess thats not possible in general